# Why does MSSQL in Docker return "The last operation was terminated because the user pressed CTRL+C" on sql queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, docker

I'm on Archlinux 64x (4.17.4-1-ARCH) with Docker (version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa8257ec). I'm using [Microsoft's MSSQL](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) docker container CU7. Each time I'm trying to enter a query or to run a SQL file I get this warning message:

```
Sqlcmd: Warning: The last operation was terminated because the user pressed CTRL+C.
```

Then when I check in the database with Datagrip, the query hasn't been executed! Here are my commands :

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU7
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=GitGood*0987654321" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -p 1433:1433 --name beep_boop_boop -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU7

# THIS

sudo echo "CREATE DATABASE test;" > /test.sql
docker exec beep_boop_boop /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P GitGood*0987654321 < test.sql

# OR

docker exec beep_boop_boop /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P GitGood*0987654321 -Q "CREATE DATABASE test;"
```

My question is **How to avoid Warning `operation was terminated by user` warning on MSSQL queries?**

Comment: I get the same thing from ubuntu trusty with travisCI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), I'm sure it will make your life easier. My guess is you're getting an error without actually knowing it. First time I tried, I used an unsafe password which didn't meet security requirements and I got this error:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols..

I see your password is strong, but note that you have a `*` in your password, which may be *executed* if not correctly escaped.

Or the server is just not started when running with your command line, example:

```bash
# example of a failing attempt
docker run -it --rm -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=GitGood*0987654321' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU7 bash
# wait until you're inside the container, then check if server is running
apt-get update && apt-get install -y nmap
nmap -Pn localhost -p 1433
```

If it's not running, you'll see something like that:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-27 06:12 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000083s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1433/tcp closed ms-sql-s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.38 seconds
```

### Enough with the intro, here's a working solution:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU7
    container_name: beep-boop-boop
    ports:
      - 1443:1443
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: GitGood*0987654321
```

Then run the following commands and wait until the image is ready:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs -f &
```

- `up -d` to demonize the container so it keeps running in the background.
- `logs -f` will read logs and *follow* (similar to what `tail -f` does)
- `&` to run the command in the background so we don't need to use a new shell

Now get a bash running inside that container like this:

```
docker-compose exec db bash
```

Once inside the image, you can run your commands

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "CREATE DATABASE test;"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases"
```

Note how I reused the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable here so I didn't need to retype the password.

Now enjoy the result

```
name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master
tempdb
model
msdb
test

(5 rows affected)
```

For a proper setup, I recommend replacing the `environment` key with the following lines in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
env_file:
  - .env
```

This way, you can store your secrets outside of your `docker-compose.yml` and also make sure you don't track `.env` in your version control (you should add `.env` to your `.gitignore` and provide a `.env.example` in your repository with proper documentation.

Here's an example project which confirms it works in Travis-CI:
https://github.com/GabLeRoux/mssql-docker-compose-example

### Other improvements

There are probably some other ways to accomplish this with one liners, but for readability, it's often better to just use some scripts. In the repo, I took a few shortcuts such as `sleep 10` in `run.sh`. This could be improved by actually waiting until the db is up with a proper way. The initialization script could also be part of an `entrypoint.sh`, etc. Hope it gets you started

Comment: This answer, whilst accepted, doesn't actually address the question. Running the piped-input using docker-compose or straight docker fails with the error the OP posted, but running bash from straight docker works fine. This answer did help, however, because using `-Q 'SELECT * FROM blah'` as an argument works fine (either using docker or docker-compose).

Comment: Well I guess we can do the following from outside the docker:`docker-compose exec db bash -c '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "CREATE DATABASE test;" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases"'` (note I did not try it). Maybe there's some bash trick to make it use piped input too. Solution actually avoided the error message, but I agree with you, I did not find a way to use piped-input. I considered the workaround good enough :) If you find a way, please post it here, I'd be happy to have a better solution.

Comment: In fact, I know we could accomplish something by reading the file from inside the docker image using volumes and then using a command to read that file from inside docker.